# How do I keep my box element from distorting or getting out of shape when shown on different size browsers

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to this and I want to make a place to display products which I have successfully done however when it opens on a window that is not full screen it takes the shape of that window and distorts the product image etc
how can I fix this

```
<div class="row">
{% for product in products %} 
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <img class="thumbnail" src="{{product.imageURL}}">
    <div class="box-element product">
        <p><light>{{product.name}}</light></p>
    <hr>
    <button data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn update-cart">Add to Cart</button>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="#">View</a>
    <h4 style="display: inline-block; float: right"><light>${{product.price|floatformat:2}}</light></h4>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: well where is the CSS code for it? As you not using and ID's I also assume you not using media queries (breakpoints) to specifally change the design for mobile devices. HAve you implemented media queries?

Comment: @Vince you want to keep the image size original or  fit to content?

Comment: Have you tried to put `<div class="container"></div>` around your `.row`'s?